# Why is Azure Service Bus queue at 1GB quota size with zero messages?

Tags: queue, message-queue, azureservicebus

I have some Azure Service bus queues that are hitting quota with either very small size of Active and Deadletter messages, or even zero messages.  There seem to be other messages that are neither "Active" or "Deadletter".  What are they?  Service Bus explorer indicates the following stats for a queue, for example:

[image: Service Bus Explorer screen shot]

The "Message Count" and "Transfer DL Message Count" in Service Bus Explorer are very high.  Obviously, these are what are using the space.  I can't receive/delete them in Service Bus Explorer and can't find any information about how to deal with them.

Azure reports similar.  What is a "Transfer DL Message?"

[image]

Comment: What version of SBExplorer are you using?

Comment: Service Bus Explorer - Version 3.0.4.  Azure Portal reports the same numbers.  I don't understand what the "transfer" dead letter messages are..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**
I suspect there's an issue with SBExplorer or this entity.

"Total DL Message Count" stands for [`TransferDeadLetterMessageCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagecountdetails) representing number of messages that are dead lettered. "Message Count" stands for your queue description's [`MessageCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queuedescription#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_MessageCount) which is a total number of messages in a queue. From this, it looks as if all of your messages found in that queue are DLQed.

You can peek the DLQ queue and see those messages.

- Check you're running the most up-to-date version of SBE
- If you are and this is still the case, try deleting the queue and recreating it and see if that's helping to refresh the count after using the queue for a while
- In case the problem persists, raise an issue in https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/issues

Comment: Hey, Sean, the "Transfer DL Messages" are not part of the "Dead-Letter Message Count".  See the Azure portal stat screen grab I added for the same queue.

Comment: MSDN doco: TransferDeadLetterMessageCount

- Gets or sets the number messages transferred into dead letters.
So the messages were DLQed at some point. Can you peek DLQ? Have you tried to recreate the queue?

Comment: DLQ can be peeked.  There are no messages. This is not surprising because the count is zero.  Just trying to figure out why the messages that were "transferred" to DLQ are still taking up space.  I deleted all the queues and restarted and will monitor again. The portal stat's just look strange to me.

Comment: If you'd get server side errors, I'd say take those to ASB support using the provided TrackingID. But you don't get those. So removing an entity and recreating it might address a server side issue that can happen (not often, but possible).

Comment: Since you're using NServiceBus with this queue, did you find any odd errors in the log file?

Comment: One other thing I noticed in your SBExplorer screenshot, is that queue's max size seems to be at 0 GB? Which is unusual... 1 GB is default, so it's either that SBExplorer subtracts actual size from Max when showing it (why would it), or somehow the max is corrupt, thus shutting everything down?

Comment: @Slava it's at 1GB. It starts from 1 (not zero) and goes up to 5GB. This must be server side issue with the queue entity.

Comment: @SeanFeldman after deleting all of the queues and restarting, I have not seen the issue again.  I am going to chalk it up to ASB having gotten into a bad state.  I don't believe there was an error in SBE because it and the portal showed the same stats.  Marking this as the answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it was resolved. Something to bring up to the ASB team attention.

Answer (score 1):

If you have "Transfer dead-letter messages", you must have been encountering some issues during ForwardTo or SendVia...

Explanation for the **Transfer Dead-Letter Queue** from this document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

Dead-lettering in ForwardTo or SendVia scenarios
Messages will be sent to the transfer dead-letter queue under the following conditions:+

- A message passes through more than 3 queues or topics that are
  chained together.
- The destination queue or topic is disabled or
  deleted.
- The destination queue or topic exceeds the maximum entity
  size.

To retrieve these dead-lettered messages, you can create a receiver using the FormatTransferDeadletterPath utility method.